# Conditional rendering cannot be seen due to a return before them

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-state

Please help give me a better title, I couldn't word what I am asking.

**To understand my question** I have to provide some context of my project. Originally I wanted to conditionally render two pages through two buttons. Button A rendering screen A and button B rendering screen B. After figuring out how to pass the state from a parent component to a child and its child etc, I changed my button to a sliding animation for better design.

**This causes issues** because now when a new screen is rendered, the animation does not show because it is simply re-rendered with the original starting place in the animation(I rendered the slider through each screen). I thought about providing two different sliders, each starting in the opposing opposition but that would still lose the entire slide effect.

**I have now resulted** to rendering the Slider so it is there all the time and is not re-rendered. However I have realized now that if I return it before my conditionals, that code is never reached. I have provided a working demo that shows my problem perfectly as well as the code below(I only provided App.js, the rest is on the demo if needed). I want to render Slider in App.js.

The working demo is [here](https://snack.expo.dev/@priedejm/parent-to-child-state), you can see the slider does not slide, it just changes screens. I need it to slide. Also the sliding animation only works on iphone so I would use that emulator rather than the web.

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      whichComponentToShow: "Screen1"
    };
  }

  goToMap = () => {
    this.setState({ whichComponentToShow: "Screen2" });
  };
  goToList = () => {
    this.setState({ whichComponentToShow: "Screen1" });
  };

  render() {
    const { whichComponentToShow } = this.state;
    
    /* This is how I thought I could render this, but obv it makes the rest of the code unreachable.
       How can I render this and then have the conditional page below? Each time the new page renders, 
       it stops the animation from working due to rendering the new page.
    return(
      <Slider/>
    )*/

    if(this.state.whichComponentToShow === 'Screen1'){
        return(
          <View style={{backgroundColor: '#d1cfcf' ,flex: 1}}>

            <ListHome
              renderMap = {this.goToMap.bind(this)}
              renderList = {this.goToList.bind(this)}
            />
          </View>
      );
    }
    else if(this.state.whichComponentToShow === 'Screen2'){
      return(
       <View style={{backgroundColor: '#d1cfcf' ,flex: 1}}>
       
        <MapHome
          renderMap = {this.goToMap.bind(this)}
          renderList = {this.goToList.bind(this)}
        />
  
       </View>
      );
    }
```

Slider.js (wont show up on the snack apparently

```
const Slider = (props) => {
  
  const [active, setActive] = useState(false)
  let transformX = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (active) {
      Animated.timing(transformX, {
        toValue: 1,
        duration: 300,
        useNativeDriver: true
      }).start()
    } else {
      Animated.timing(transformX, {
        toValue: 0,
        duration: 300,
        useNativeDriver: true
      }).start()
    }
  }, [active]);

  const rotationX = transformX.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: [2, Dimensions.get('screen').width / 4]
  })


  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{
      flex: 1,
      alignItems: 'center'
    }}>
      <View style={{
        flexDirection: 'row',
        position: 'relative',
        height: 45,
        width: 240,
        borderRadius: 10,
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        marginHorizontal: 5
      }}>
        <Animated.View
          style={{
            position: 'absolute',
            height: 45 - 2*2,
            top: 2,
            bottom: 2,
            borderRadius: 10,
            width: Dimensions
            .get('screen').width / 3 - 3.5 ,
            transform: [
              {
                translateX: rotationX
              }
            ],
            backgroundColor: '#d1cfcf',
          }}
        >
        </Animated.View>
        <TouchableOpacity style={{
          flex: 1,
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center'
        }} onPress={() => {setActive(false); props.renderList() }}>
          <Text>
            List
        </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity style={{
          flex: 1,
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center'
        }} onPress={() => {setActive(true); props.renderMap() }}>
          <Text>
            Map
        </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}


export default Slider
```

Comment: https://github.com/reactjs/react-transition-group

Comment: Do you mind elaborating?

Comment: It'll help with delayed renderings while animating, etc...

Comment: Unfortunately that does not help me here

Comment: With conditional rendering you can't really have such nice animation because the element is not present in the DOM. It should be rendered first and then animate. But rendering all the screens are not a good idea for performance but you could lazy load them by using [React.lazy](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#reactlazy). Like that you can still have a sliding animation with a loading animation until react fetch the js codebase

Comment: I will look into using this. I have to imagine there is a better way to go about it but I also am naïve and know nothing so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your `expo` snack and saw no code related to animation, so I'm assuming the code in the snack isn't your current code, and that you really do already have a working, animated, `<Slider ... />`.

In your situation, what you could do to keep your `Slider` rendered and not unmounted, is to use variables in the `render()` method.

Basically, you can assign the <Slider .../> JSX to a variable, and you can use that variable in another JSX part later.

Assigning a `key` to the specific JSX also helps guide React that this is the same component between render calls, so it also prevents unintentional rerenders of that component.

Here's an edit with comments from what you wrote in your post. I hope this makes sense.

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            whichComponentToShow: "Screen1"
        };
    }

    goToMap = () => {
        this.setState({ whichComponentToShow: "Screen2" });
    };
    goToList = () => {
        this.setState({ whichComponentToShow: "Screen1" });
    };

    render() {
        const { whichComponentToShow } = this.state;

        /* 
        Keep the slider JSX in a variable to be used.
        Setting a specific key also helps prevent it from being accidentally re-rendered in some conditions.
        )*/
        const sliderRender = <Slider key='slider' />;

        if (this.state.whichComponentToShow === 'Screen1') {
            return (
                <View style={{ backgroundColor: '#d1cfcf', flex: 1 }}>

                    <ListHome
                        renderMap={this.goToMap.bind(this)}
                        renderList={this.goToList.bind(this)}
                    />
                    {/* Put the rendered slider into the render tree */}
                    {sliderRender}
                </View>
            );
        }
        else if (this.state.whichComponentToShow === 'Screen2') {
            return (
                <View style={{ backgroundColor: '#d1cfcf', flex: 1 }}>

                    <MapHome
                        renderMap={this.goToMap.bind(this)}
                        renderList={this.goToList.bind(this)}
                    />
                    {/* Put the rendered slider into the render tree */}
                    {sliderRender}
                </View>
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Edit : [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@switt/slider-fix-for-sof) demonstrating it working

[image]

Comment: Slider.js is in the demo at the bottom of the file tree and it contains all of the code for the Slider button. As for rendering the button the way you did as a variable. I seem to have some state problems as well as some render problems. Could you update the snack to include your implementation to confirm it works?

I would appreciate it more than you know.

Comment: Your snack's slider.js code is this. It doesn't contain any animations in its current form.
```
const Slider = (props) => {
  return (
    <View style={{ backgroundColor: "#ccc", flex: 1 }}>
      <Text>Slider</Text>
     
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {props.renderMap; }}>
        <Text> Map </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {props.renderList; }}>
        <Text> List </Text>
     </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thats weird... snack must be doing something to it. Let me update the snack and try and get you that code.

Comment: https://snack.expo.dev/@priedejm/785712 This should work, I posted the code on the post as well.

Comment: Let me know if you need anything else, I appreciate the effort @switt

Comment: The new snack link in the comment works . I've since updated my answer with the edited Expo Snack. Which I hope works as you expected.

Comment: You sir, are a genius. Thank you.